# Rails advanced searching with datetimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, datetime, advanced-search

I'm working on an app that will allow users to search for any recordings we have in a database, organized by three values: agent (name), phone, and date. date is recorded as a datetime value. I want to provide advanced search features that will allow users to select time ranges following this guideline:

Year: entered into a text field
Month: entered into a text field
Day: entered into a text field
Hours: two select lists representing a range upper and lower bound
Minutes: two select lists representing a range upper and lower bound

I watched [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form) for help on how to get started with the search logic, but I'm concerned because I don't know how to pass in dateparts into Rails queries. Normally you would run something like `select date_part(hh, date) as date_hour from table_name` to get the value of hour, but how would you do that in Rails, or in the way Ryan Bates suggests in his Railscast?

Comment: what you tried till now?

Comment: I have text fields for name and phone number that will provide the correct search results. I just don't know how to format the conditions within the search model to run the `date_part()` query in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You may concat the values in the controller accessing them by the `params` and then parse to a datetime

Then [DateTime.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000214) allows you to specify the format and convert a String to a DateTime.